# Grep single quote and dollar sign

Tags: regex, grep

It is easy to grep a single quote mark if you put it inside a double quoting mark:

```
grep file.txt "'"
```

It is easy to grep a dollar sign if you put it inside single quotes:

```
grep file.txt '\$'
```

because "\$" won't work.

How to grep both single quote mark and dollar sign in the same grep command?

Comment: You may use: `grep "[$']" file`

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a regex character class `[]`:

```
grep "[$']" file.txt
```

Comment: Actually, in the POSIX "world", `[...]` is called a *bracket expression* (there is a certain [difference between them and NFA character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html))